# VBA to automate dropdown list navigation in Excel worksheet

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I am trying to create a dropdown box in an Excel worksheet that when selected will navigate to a specific row on the page. So far I have got what is below which works fine. Thing is though, I might have a worksheet which is thousands of lines long and I obviously don't want to write through 'Case Is = 1000' etc. on my script as this is long and tedious. The 'Case Is' would be incrementing by 1 each time and the range would be incrementing by 21 each time. I know that what I want is a looping process but I'm just unsure how to go about this.

```
Sub Worksheet_Dropdown()
Select Case Range("B1").Value
    Case Is = 1
    Application.Goto Range("B3"), Scroll:=True

    Case Is = 2
    Application.Goto Range("B24"), Scroll:=True

    Case Is = 3
    Application.Goto Range("B45"), Scroll:=True

End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Goto Range("B" & 3+(Range("B1").Value-1)*21), Scroll:=True`

Comment: That worked great; the answer seems so simple, too. Thank you.